# How to implement twitter share with image file in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to implement twitter share in my flutter application.
I convert my widget to image by using `RepaintBoundary` and stored as `ByteData` as below.

```
  Future<ByteData> convertWidgetToImage(GlobalKey key) async {
    final RenderRepaintBoundary boundary =
        key.currentContext!.findRenderObject() as RenderRepaintBoundary;

    final image = await boundary.toImage();
    final byteData = await image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);
    return byteData!;
  }
```

Then, I want to open twitter app with some default text and with this image data. (I can convert this bytedata to local file path url if needed as below)

```
Future<String> get _localPath async {
  final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

  return directory.path;
}
```

Is there any way I can share this image to twitter (onTap then open twitter app with this image)?
This could be an option but I don't think I can share twitter image
https://pub.dev/packages/social_share

Comment: try this pkg bro ==> https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_share_me

Comment: yeah but that doesn't have imagePath share option in Twitter

Comment: try this bro ==> https://pub.dev/packages/esys_flutter_share   and also read this

Comment: hey husky, have you found a solution for this? Also would like to share directly to twitter.